# Click event is not working for dynamically changed class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two class .btnn and .sleep_avail sometimes i changes the css of a anchor from .btnn to .sleep_avail

Now i have two function for anchor click

```
 $('.btnn').click(function () {
     alert('yes btn');
 });
```

And Second one is

```
$('.sleep_avail').click(function () {
    alert('yes sleep');
});
```

Now when i click on the anchor with class sleep_avail which is changed dynamically from btnn class the event written for btnn raised and i get response accordingly. But what i need is that the event for sleep_avail should be raised. Kindly help.

Comment: there are many many many posts with same issue. search in SO.

Comment: A fiddle explaining the steps to reproduce the issues, and what is the desired effect would help a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anytime, you use dynamically created tags, you must use

```
$(document).on('#event','#selector',function () {...});
```

so here

```
$(document).on('click','.sleep_avail',function () {...});
```

Because event handlers bind to the currently elements, they have to exist on the page when `.on()`is called

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working **DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/ARBdU/

```
$(document).on('click','.btnn, .sleep_avail',function () {  
 if($(this).hasClass('btnn'))
 {
    ...   
 }
 else if($(this).hasClass('sleep_avail'))
 {      
   ...
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**try**

```
$(document).on('click','.sleep_avail',function () {
```